# React-bootstrap-table: Warning: Component's children should not be mutated

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I use this short example snippet in my code

```
<BootstrapTable data={products}>
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField="id" isKey={true}>Product ID</TableHeaderColumn>
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField="name">Product Name</TableHeaderColumn>
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField="price">Product Price</TableHeaderColumn>
</BootstrapTable>
```

And everything's work perfect. There's table, there's data. But (!) I see next warning message in my Chrome console:

[image]

whereas if I use my own elements, there's no warnings..
What's wrong? How to fix it?

Comment: Checkout this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39709113/components-children-should-not-be-mutated

Comment: If you won't figure it our please create a working demo which reproduces this issue, the code you've included here is incomplete.