# Component's children should not be mutated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a `react-redux` app. I get data via AJAX part of Redux store. This part looks like this:

```
    counts: {
        warning: 0,
        new: 0,
        in_hands: 0,
        completed: 0,
        rejected: 0
    }
```

After changing this values React renders the component

```
render() {

        var counts = [
            {
                id: 'warning',
                count: parseInt(this.props.counts.warning),
                name: 'Внимение'
            },
            {
                id: 'new',
                count: parseInt(this.props.counts.new),
                name: 'Новые'
            },
            {
                id: 'in_hands',
                count: parseInt(this.props.counts.in_hands),
                name: 'В работе'
            },
            {
                id: 'completed',
                count: parseInt(this.props.counts.completed),
                name: 'Выполн.'
            },
            {
                id: 'rejected',
                count: parseInt(this.props.counts.rejected),
                name: 'Отменен.'
            }
        ];

    content = (<div className="inside-loader"/>);

    return(
        <div>
        <Tabs key="tabs_order-list" id="order-list" items={counts} defaultTab="warning" changeList={this.changeList} content={content}/></div>
    )
}
```

inside `Tabs` component we can see this:

```
render() {
        let self = this;
        let items = this.props.items.map(function (item, index) {
            return <div key={self.props.id+'_'+index} onClick={self.changeTab.bind(null, item.id)} className={'bar-tabs__tab ' + (self.state.openedTabId == item.id ? 'active' : '')}>
                <b>{item.count}</b>
                <span>{item.name}</span>
            </div>
        })
        return <div>
            <div className={'bar-tabs bar-tabs__' + this.props.id}>{items}</div>
            <div className={'bar-tabs-content bar-tabs-content__' + this.props.id}>
                <div className='bar-tabs-content__tab active'>{this.props.content}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

However, in the console I see this:

[screen of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRTkp.png)

I read about similar problems and I understand that this warning occurs when I try to change `props` values. But I didn't change `props` values.

Comment: does `changeTab` function that you bind with `null` have access to props or state? cause it seems it's going to mutate something. And `<div className="inside-loader"/>` is a div self-closing tag which I think isn't allowed. And then you pass that self closing div down to a prop.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you positive that all of your `count`s are valid numbers? You should `console.log` the `counts` array in the first `render()` and check that none of the `count` values in each object of the array are `NaN`. If any of them is `NaN`, it might be related to this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7424.

Simply check that your data is correct and you are not getting `NaN` after you `parseInt`.